# How to open a mailto link with a click on a Chrome extension icon?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, mailto

With the following code I try to open a `mailto:` link in a tab if the user clicks on the Chrome extension icon. However, upon click on the icon, no action is being performed.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Extension",
  "description": "Description",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

**popup.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function tab) {
  var emailUrl = "mailto:address@domain.com";
  chrome.tabs.create({ url: emailUrl });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multible issues with your code:

1. You never require you popup.js.
2. You JavaScript code is invalid.

I recommend using an eventPage to trigger the E-Mail link:

**manifest.json**

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Extension",
  "description": "Description",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["eventPage.js"],
    "persistent": false
  }
}
```

**eventPage.js**

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(tab => {
  chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'mailto:address@domain.com' })
})
```